# What's wrong with my bash array?

Tags: bash

Can anyone tell me why this bash script works if I cut and paste it to the terminal but throws "server_prep.sh: 7: Syntax error: "(" unexpected" when launched using $ sudo sh server_prep.sh ?

```
#!/bin/sh

#Packages
apt-get -y install ssh libsqlite3-dev ruby-full mercurial

#Gems
required_gems = ( rake rails sqlite3-ruby )

#Set up directories
[ ! -d /var/www ] && mkdir /var/www
[ ! -d /var/www/apps ] && mkdir /var/www/apps

#install gems manually
if ! which gem >/dev/null; then
    wget http://rubyforge.org/frs/download.php/60718/rubygems-1.3.5.tgz
    tar xvfz rubygems-1.3.5.tgz
    ruby rubygems-1.3.5/setup.rb
    ln -s /usr/bin/gem1.8 /usr/bin/gem
    gem update --system

    #Tidy Up
    rm -rf rubygems-1.3.5.tgz rubygems-1.3.5
fi

#Install required gems
for required_gem in "${required_gems[@]}"
do
    if ! gem list | grep $required_gem >/dev/null; then
        gem install $required_gems
    fi
done
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your script is using sh, not bash, when it's executed. There could be a minor syntax difference between the two.

Try changing `!#/bin/sh`  to `!#/bin/bash` at the top of your script

Answer (score 8):

You can't have spaces when assigning variables in sh/bash.
It has to be:

```
required_gems=( rake rails sqlite3-ruby )
```

In any case, it doesn't have to be an array, you could just do:

```
required_gems="fake rails sqlite3-ruby"
```

and then

```
for required_gem in ${required_gems}; do
  blah blah
done
```

Notice there are no "" around ${required_gems}

Comment: +1 You can usually use string lists instead of arrays. I don't think I've ever used an array in bash in the 10 years I've been programming in it.

Comment: Indeed. The only time I use arrays in bash, is when I have several vars describing the same object. For example, when I have a service name/executable/description/sampling interval.

Answer (score 2):

The third to last line, should `$required_gems` read `$required_gem`?

Comment: doubleplus good.